# Azure Websites Custom Domains - Doesn't support CNAME to A records?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

We are trying to add a third party domain to our Azure website (which is part of an Azure Traffic Manager BTW, but that shouldn't matter).

The manage custom domains won't allow us to add the binding.

Here's the scenario.

> myapp.com = the domain we own.
>
> myapp.clientcompany.com = the domain we DON'T own.

We have added an A record for myapp.com which points to the IP address of the traffic manager (the section that says "The IP Address to use when you configure A record"), and our client has added a CNAME record for myapp.clientcompany.com to myapp.com.

eg.

> 1.2.3.4 A myapp.com
>
> myapp.clientcomapny.com CNAME myapp.com

However, the manage custom domains is still complaining when we try and add myapp.clientcompany.com. It says it can't find a CNAME record.
This should work. myapp.clientcompany.com is CNAME'd to myapp.com which is a A record pointing to the traffic manager. The actual DNS is resolving fine as it's displaying the Azure webpage saying website doesn't exist.

Also - we cannot use the awverify CNAME technique, as we don't own the client's domain, and we can't expect them to add a CNAME to Azure (this essentially exposes our infrastructure to them).

Anyone got this to work? Is the only solution to get the client to CNAME to a CNAME record? (e.g myapp.clientcompany.com CNAME www.myapp.com CNAME myapp.trafficmanager.net)

Note: Please don't answer just pointing me to a "how to" on custom bindings with Azure Websites - i've read them all. I've got it working for CNAME's, but it doesn't seem to work for CNAME's to A records.

Comment: Could you please give your azure website name and the actual domain  you are trying to map it to ?

Comment: @RanjithRamachandra - do you have an email/twitter account i can DM? I don't really want to give that information to the public.

Comment: https://twitter.com/ranjithtweeets

Comment: @RanjithRamachandra - tweeted.

Comment: @RanjithRamachandra - did you get my DM?